# Handling large volume of data using Web API

Tags: sql-server, rest, asp.net-web-api, large-data

We have a long running DB query that populates a temporary table (we are not supposed to change this behavior) which results 6 to 10 million records, around 4  to 6 GB data.

I need to use .NET Web API for fetching data from SQL DB and the API is hosted on IIS. When a request comes from the client to API, query runs minimum 5 minutes based on amount of data in different joining tables and populates temp table. Then API has to read data from DB temp table and send it to client.

Without blocking client, without loosing DB temp table, without blocking IIS, how can we achieve this requirement?

Just thinking, if I use async API, will I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

there are things you need to consider and things you can do.

if you kick off the query execution as the result of an API call, what happens if you get 10 calls to that endpoint, at the same time? Dead API, that's what going to happen.

You might be able to find a different trigger for the execution of the query, so you can run this query once per day for example or once every 4 hours and then store the result in a permanent table. The APIs job then only becomes to look at this table, not wait for anything and return some data.

The second thing you can do is to return only the data you need for the screen you are displaying. You are not going to show 4-6 gb worth of data in one go, I suspect you have some pagination there and you can rejig the code a little to only return one page of data in one go.

You don't say what kind of data you have, but if it something which doesn't require you to run that query very often then you can definitely make some improvements.

<---- edited after report clarification ---->

ok, since it's a report, here's another idea.

the aim is to make sure that the pressure is not on the api itself which needs to be responsive and quick. Let the API receive the request with the parameters needed. Offload the actual report generation activity to another service.

1. Keep track of what this service is doing so you can report on the status of the activity : has it started, is it finished, whatever else you need. You can use a queue for that, or simply keep track of jobs in the database.
2. generate the report file and store it somewhere.
3. email the user with the file attached or email a link so the user can download it. Another option is to provide a link to the report somewhere in the UI.

Comment: Its a report that we are trying to create, parameters are supplied by the user which are going to vary, so we can't have a trigger that generates the data. Its required to get the whole data in one shot as data is going to be exported to different file formats

Comment: How about the idea of Queuing? As soon as queue is processed, it can place data in a permanent table as you said or export to file from temp table. We can set a flag and the client can poll reading the flag. When the flag is read as done, client gives another call to fetch data. Data now can be retrieved in streaming?

Comment: added more to my answer